# CakePHP findallby returns empty string

Tags: cakephp, recursion, has-many, belongs-to, findall

I got a problem with my cakePHP App.

Here are two queries:

```
$this->Link->findAllByLink($imdbid)
$this->Link->findByLink($imdbid)
```

The second one returns an array with a single Item and its `$hasMany` values, which is ok.
But the `findallbylink` returns empty? Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
Item has many Link,
Link belongs to Item.
Link recursive = 2.
```

If I don't set recursive, the `findallbylink` will return all the `Items` but without the `hasMany` values.

If you have any further questions i will try to reply quickly.

Kind Regards Pete

Comment: I tried formatting your question better. I saw the three lines with "Item has many Link etc" which seemed like they needed to be formatted, but they don't look like code to me. What are they? Try to edit your answer and format those lines better.

Comment: ah thank you for formatting, the three lines are Associations between the Model Item and Link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using ID instead of Link?

```
$this->Link->findById($imdbid);
$this->Link->findAllById($imdbid);
```

Can't be sure, as you don't show your table structure, but - your current code seems a bit strange, since you're looking for a "Link" with field 'link' to equal $imdbid (an ID I presume).